# ntdll.dll [Frames below may be incorrect /missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll]

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, shared-ptr

since a few weeks now I have run into this situation and it very upsetting,

my program debugs very well, no errors, when I run the program it does the initial part of the 
job, after a few seconds It terminates to a 'break continue' option, and in the call stack when I have a look, it turns out that its an error from ntdll.dll and msvcr100d.dll 
it seems like a windows related SDK problem, it seems like a bad pointer too.
I have somehow no control over this.
I installed windows SDK to 7.0 but nothing seems to change,

Using : Windows 7 64 bit, Boost 1.48, Visual studio compiler (full version), openCV2.3, c++.

I have tried many options,

eg. to go to the task manager, and with a right click on devenv.exe and selecting only one in the 'set affinity'
reinstalling windows SDK, 
Reinstalling several times my own project.

Nothing has helped me, can some one suggest me a good solution please.

for more clarity here is my call stack

```
ntdll.dll!77e615de()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!77e615de()    
ntdll.dll!77e5014e()    
msvcr100d.dll!_getptd_noexit()  Line 500    C
ntdll.dll!77eb73bc()    
ntdll.dll!77ea3c48()    
ntdll.dll!77e5016e()    
msvcr100d.dll!_getptd_noexit()  Line 500    C
ntdll.dll!77eb74df()    
ntdll.dll!77eb73bc()    
ntdll.dll!77ea3c48()    
ntdll.dll!77e5016e()    
msvcr100d.dll!_getptd_noexit()  Line 500    C
ntdll.dll!77eb74df()    
ntdll.dll!77eb73bc()    
ntdll.dll!77ea3c48()    
ntdll.dll!77e5016e()    
msvcr100d.dll!_getptd_noexit()  Line 500    C
ntdll.dll!77eb74df()    
ntdll.dll!77eb73bc()    
ntdll.dll!77ea3c48()    
kernel32.dll!770012ea()     
kernel32.dll!77001314()     
msvcr100d.dll!_getptd_noexit()  Line 500    C
ntdll.dll!77eb74df()    
ntdll.dll!77eb73bc()    
ntdll.dll!77ea3c48()    
ntdll.dll!77e5016e()    
msvcr100d.dll!_getptd_noexit()  Line 500    C
ntdll.dll!77e9b459()    
ntdll.dll!77e9b42b()    
bowExample.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> >::clear()  Line 1415  C++
bowExample.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> >::erase(std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> > > _First, std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> > > _Last)  Line 1383 C++
bowExample.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> >::_Tidy()  Line 1866 + 0x5d bytes C++
bowExample.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> >::~_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> >()  Line 792 C++
bowExample.exe!std::set<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> >::~set<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> >()  + 0x2b bytes   C++
bowExample.exe!set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> >::~set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> >()  + 0x63 bytes  C++
bowExample.exe!set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> >::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2b bytes   C++
bowExample.exe!boost::checked_delete<set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> > >(set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> > * x)  Line 34 + 0x2b bytes C++
bowExample.exe!boost::scoped_ptr<set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> > >::~scoped_ptr<set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> > >()  Line 80 + 0xb bytes  C++
bowExample.exe!bowTest(CBoWIMUParams & BOWIMUPARAMS)  Line 192 + 0xf bytes  C++
bowExample.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv)  Line 225 + 0xc bytes  C++
bowExample.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 555 + 0x19 bytes   C
bowExample.exe!mainCRTStartup()  Line 371   C
kernel32.dll!7700339a()     
ntdll.dll!77e79ef2()    
ntdll.dll!77e79ec5()
```

---

Here is the call stack after loading symbols

```
ntdll.dll!_ZwRaiseException@12()  + 0x12 bytes  
ntdll.dll!_ZwRaiseException@12()  + 0x12 bytes  
msvcr100d.dll!__getptd_noexit()  + 0xae bytes   

bowExample.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> >::clear()  Line 1415  C++
bowExample.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> >::erase(std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> > > _First, std::_Tree_const_iterator<std::_Tree_val<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> > > _Last)  Line 1383 C++
bowExample.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> >::_Tidy()  Line 1866 + 0x5d bytes C++
bowExample.exe!std::_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> >::~_Tree<std::_Tset_traits<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128>,0> >()  Line 792 C++
bowExample.exe!std::set<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> >::~set<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> >()  + 0x2b bytes   C++
bowExample.exe!set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> >::~set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> >()  + 0x63 bytes  C++
bowExample.exe!set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> >::`scalar deleting destructor'()  + 0x2b bytes   C++
bowExample.exe!boost::checked_delete<set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> > >(set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> > * x)  Line 34 + 0x2b bytes C++
bowExample.exe!boost::scoped_ptr<set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> > >::~scoped_ptr<set2<CBoWMatch<int>,CBoWMatch<int>::MatchSort,CIndividualPool_NoFree_Allocator<CBoWMatch<int>,128> > >()  Line 80 + 0xb bytes  C++
bowExample.exe!bowTest(CBoWIMUParams & BOWIMUPARAMS)  Line 193 + 0xf bytes  C++
bowExample.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv)  Line 216 + 0xc bytes  C++
bowExample.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 555 + 0x19 bytes   C
bowExample.exe!mainCRTStartup()  Line 371   C
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

Comment: Hopefully helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows

Comment: You have no control over this? Usually, the answer to errors caused by invalid pointers is to not pass invalid pointers. If it's an MS bug (which I consider highly unlikely but not impossible), please show so by including a simple application that obviously is bug-free, but results in the errors you describe.

Comment: Looking at the bottom of the trace, it looks like you have a class `set2`, possibly derived from `std::set`. I would start looking there, plus what the function `bowTest` does to its `scoped_ptr`. The odds for finding the bug there is *much* higher that in boost or the compiler standard library.

Comment: sarnold : I dont knw how your link will help, but I will have a look at it closely in a few minutes

Comment: hvd : I wish it was that simple to produce it. most importantly its going into boost headers and this is very complex to understand.This is why I am finding it difficult.
I will see if I can produce it. Thanks

Comment: Bo Persson : The set2 is coming from scoped_ptr.hpp from boost. I will again have a look at bowtest once again and will get back

Comment: As stated in my answer, until you download the debug symbols from microsoft you may be looking at a wrong stack trace.

Comment: @timothy Assuming you haven't modified the Boost headers, a simple application that uses Boost and causes this problem would also be a good sample. If you do that, you don't need to understand how Boost is doing what it does, you only need to understand what your own program is doing.

Comment: @hvd Without symbols the stack trace may be simply wrong, no matter where the error is. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416588(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @PaoloBrandoli Correction appreciated, previous comment withdrawn :)

Comment: You should post the content of main and bowTest

Answer (score 14):

Right click on the stack line (in the stack trace) containing ntdll.dll and load the debugging symbols from the Microsoft server (Load symbols from...), then the stack trace will probably change a bit. Repeat the operation for each dll with undefined symbols.

Until you download the debugging symbols you are probably looking at a wrong stack trace.

Comment: Paolo: yes it changed a little bit but I cant gain any clarity in the problem, thanks

Comment: Try to repeat the operation for all the dlls with no symbols

Comment: The dlls in use are   
ntdll.dll!_ZwRaiseException@12()  + 0x12 bytes,   msvcr100d.dll!__getptd_noexit()  + 0xae bytes, and   kernel32.dll!_UnhandledExceptionFilter@4()  + 0x11d bytes

Comment: @timothy Can you re-post the stack trace after the symbols have been loaded?

Answer (score 0):

This started happening to me for no apparent reason. After looking at the project properties I noticed the Working Directory was somehow deleted (it was just blank), after setting it back to the correct directory everything started working again.

Obviously my simple fix might not work for you, I got lucky.