# Visual Studio Professional 2012 svhost32.exe error running hello world

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, vshost.exe

I am new to Microsoft Visual Studio and have just installed Visual Studio 2012 on my computer. I am trying to run a simple hello world console application. This is my code:

```
using System;


namespace HelloWorld
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
        }
    }
}
```

when I run this either for debug or release it correctly displays the hello world in the console but then promptly gives me this error message: "vshost32.exe has stopped working" after researching the problem I figured out how to go into properties and unselect "Enable the visual Studio hosting process" which is what seemed to fix the problem for other people. But then when I try to run the code again all I get is "HelloWorld has stopped working". Does anyone have any ideas of what I could try next? Most solutions for this problem had to do with errors in peoples code but that seems a little hard to imagine since its hello world.

when I enable native code debugging this is the error message that I get:

> First-chance exception at 0x77e3f9f2 in HelloWorld.exe: 0xC0000008: An invalid handle was specified.

This is the Call Stack

```
ntdll.dll!77e3f9f2()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll] 
ntdll.dll!77e3f9f2()    
KernelBase.dll!76dbc455()   
kernel32.dll!76cb1408()     
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b8c60d()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78ecb()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78f9e()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b741d4()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7432f()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7439a()    
ntdll.dll!77e599a0()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d702()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d5a4()    
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
kernel32.dll!76cb1408()     
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b8c60d()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78ecb()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78f9e()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b741d4()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7432f()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7439a()    
ntdll.dll!77e599a0()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d702()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d5a4()    
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b8c60d()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78ecb()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78f9e()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b741d4()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7432f()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7439a()    
ntdll.dll!77e599a0()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d702()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d5a4()    
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78ecb()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78f9e()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b741d4()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7432f()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7439a()    
ntdll.dll!77e599a0()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d702()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d5a4()    
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78f9e()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b741d4()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7432f()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7439a()    
ntdll.dll!77e599a0()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d702()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d5a4()    
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
 mscoreei.dll!706f3712()    
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7432f()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7439a()    
ntdll.dll!77e599a0()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d702()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d5a4()    
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7439a()    
ntdll.dll!77e599a0()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d702()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d5a4()    
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
ntdll.dll!77e599a0()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d702()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d5a4()    
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
ntdll.dll!77e6d702()    
ntdll.dll!77e6d5a4()    
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
ntdll.dll!77e6d5a4()    
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
mscoreei.dll!706f3712()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3126()     
mscoreei.dll!706e3216()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48ef()     
mscoreei.dll!706e4928()     
mscoreei.dll!706e47b0()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48a2()     
mscoreei.dll!706e48be()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
mscoreei.dll!706f38c4()     
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
clr.dll!701f2e27()  
clr.dll!701f2daa()  
clr.dll!701901df()  
clr.dll!70190226()  
clr.dll!7016c3d2()  
mscoreei.dll!706ef5a3()     
mscoree.dll!70767f16()  
mscoree.dll!70764de3()  
kernel32.dll!76cb336a()     
ntdll.dll!77e59f72()    
ntdll.dll!77e59f45()
```

this is the new stack call after following the suggestions for getting symbols from microsoft.

```
ntdll.dll!_ZwClose@4()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!_ZwClose@4()  + 0x12 bytes    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b8c60d()    
[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for AME_OutlookSensor.dll] 
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78ecb()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b78f9e()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b741d4()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7432f()    
AME_OutlookSensor.dll!74b7439a()    
ntdll.dll!_LdrpCallInitRoutine@16()  + 0x14 bytes   
ntdll.dll!_LdrShutdownProcess@0()  + 0x141 bytes    
ntdll.dll!_RtlExitUserProcess@4()  + 0x74 bytes 
kernel32.dll!76cb79c5()     
mscoreei.dll!RuntimeDesc::ShutdownAllActiveRuntimes()  + 0x10e bytes    
mscoreei.dll!CLRRuntimeHostInternalImpl::ShutdownAllRuntimesThenExit()  + 0x13  bytes   
clr.dll!EEPolicy::ExitProcessViaShim()  + 0x65 bytes    
clr.dll!SafeExitProcess()  + 0x7d bytes 
clr.dll!DisableRuntime()  - 0xce069 bytes   
clr.dll!EEPolicy::HandleExitProcess()  + 0x42 bytes 
clr.dll!__CorExeMainInternal@0()  + 0xf2 bytes  
clr.dll!__CorExeMain@0()  + 0x1c bytes  
mscoreei.dll!__CorExeMain@0()  + 0x71 bytes 
mscoree.dll!_ShellShim__CorExeMain@0()  + 0x227 bytes   
mscoree.dll!__CorExeMain_Exported@0()  + 0x8 bytes  
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

Comment: are you running Visual Studio as Administrator?

Comment: Same thing happens either way, doesn't seem to matter if I run as Administrator or not.

Comment: have you tried starting from scratch? like with a brand new Console project?

Comment: Yep, I've tried starting from scratch, I've tried restarting the program and starting from scratch. Nothing. I can create a windows forms application, that runs just fine.  But not console. And its not like the console project isn't running, its just not terminating properly or something.  The one thing I haven't tried is compiling and running from command line. But ideally I'd like to have my visual studio working.

Comment: should probably check to see that the process is terminating on your machine, if you are receiving an error there you might be leaving a process open,  then again it may be something simple in your settings somewhere. I would do some more google searching on the issues in your stack though for sure and the error that is popping up. it would be easier for you to troubleshoot that way than for me to do it, you know what I mean?

Comment: yeah I know, believe me I've been looking. At this point I'm just about ready to give up and resign myself to my program crashing every time it terminates.  Thanks for the feedback, really appreciate it.

Comment: did you happen to find the solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking at your stack trace and I took the first line that jumped out at me as something was wrong.

> [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll]

I searched Google and found the answer to the Question on [*[Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for ntdll.dll]*](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d492a49f-0402-41e0-b77f-f8828b23b491/frames-below-may-be-incorrect-andor-missing-no-symbols-loaded-for-ntdlldll)

I don't know if this will work or if you need to go through and try to load the Debugging symbols like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10993377/1214743) suggests

I tried to run this exact same code on my machine using VS2010 and had no issues.

Comment: I did everything the link suggested, which has changed my stack trace a bit but not significantly.  The problem still persists.  I will post new stack trace.  Thanks for the help.  Also, I'm not really surprised that the code is working for you, what I don't understand is how does a hello world program crash? cheers for Microsoft?

Comment: I totally agree with you, how does a `Hello World` application crash? not really a comment to anything, but to keep the Console from closing before I can see the results I threw in a `Console.ReadLine()` so it wouldn't close until I wanted it to.

Comment: Hmm... well that is actually kind of a hack around for my problem. The code doesn't actually crash until the program is about to terminate... so if I add `Console.ReadLine()` it doesn't crash until a press enter :) Not really a solution, but it is less frustrating feedback.