# Frames Below maybe incorrect or missing

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, installation

I have a WPF application for which i have made an installation package using installshield and included all the necessary files. and when i install it on the same system that it was developed(windows 8.1) it works fine. but when i install it on the other system (windows 8) it throws an exception and when i debug it (using VS2008) it says the `Frames Below maybe incorrect or missing, no symbols loaded for clr.dll` and few other dlls such as `mascorelib.ni.dll` and `PresentationCore.ni.dll` i have a tight deadline please help and please tell me what are symbols and how are they shipped with installtion package.

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess is that you are missing some dll's that your application references. In particular, you could try installing the latest .Net Framework on the other machine. After it is installed, if it still doesn't work, try building, and moving the entire output folder (bin folder) to the new machine and running the executable again. Hope this helps!

Comment: I have the latest .Net framework installed and my application startsup fine but it throws an exception when i try to login and i cheked the connection string and everything else seems to be fine. can there be any other reason

Comment: I tried and moved the whole project to another system and it still throws the same exception can you please help.

Comment: Try this; create a brand new project, build it and copy the bin folder over to the other computer and try running it. Are you getting the error still? Here are some links for people with similar issues... [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10992712/ntdll-dll-frames-below-may-be-incorrect-missing-no-symbols-loaded-for-ntdll-d) [link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows) [link3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16440991/buffer-overrun-during-garbage-collection-psychic-debugging-request)